Why GNU parallel used with exported Bash function with an argument enclosed in <> leads to "No such file or directory"?
Scenario:
$ doit () { echo $1; } ; export -f doit ; doit "<xxx>"
<xxx>

$ doit () { echo $1; } ; export -f doit ; parallel doit "<xxx>" ::: 1
/usr/bin/bash: line 1: xxx: No such file or directory

Why GNU parallel used with exported Bash function (doit) with an argument enclosed in <> (<xxx>) leads to No such file or directory?
How to fix?

it looks like the argument <xxx> is interpreted as a redirection by the shell running doit.
you could try something like doit () { echo $1; } ; export -f doit ; parallel doit '"<xxx>"' ::: 1 to check if it is the case

@user24246119 Thanks, your command works. I've changed parallel doit $x to parallel doit \'$x\'. Perhaps there is more elegant / correct way?

you can use the usual pattern to protect again wrong eval. e.g.: printf -v command '%q' "doit $x" ; parrallel "${command}" or parallel doit "${x@Q}"

Most direct way to fix this is : parallel doit "\\<xxx\\>" ::: 1

As noted by @user24246119, the problem is: <xxx> is interpreted as a shell redirection.
Remember that parallel, without any {} occurrence in the commands, will place the argument at the end of the command.
So the command executed by parallel is doit <xxx> 1 in this case (xxx is a file use as stdin, and 1 a file for stdout).
You can see that a file 1 is created if you execute your command while the file xxx exists.
You have different possibilities to solve this issue, e.g.:

use 2 levels of quoting: parallel doit '"<xxx>"' ::: 1
let parallel quote it automatically (only works for simple commands like this case): parallel -q doit '<xxx>' ::: 1
or if you string is stored in a variable x=<xxx>, you can escape it with ${x@Q}: parallel doit "${x@Q}" ::: 1

